# pycharm http client send request to Django runserver "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: python, django, request, pycharm

> Pycharm 2020.1 & Python 3.7.2 both Django 2.2.12 & 3.0.5 has below issue in dev server

when sending a request with Pycharm HTTP integrated client (*.http)

```
###
GET {{url}}/order/
Accept: application/json
Cookie: sessionid={{sessionid}}
```

I got this error now and then.

```sh
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 29, 2020 - 08:41:27
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'proj.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[29/Apr/2020 08:41:53] "GET /api/order/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5070
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49554)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/CK/Git/QIF/inventory/proj/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/CK/Git/QIF/inventory/proj/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

upgrade python to 3.8.2 doesn't work.

```sh
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[29/Apr/2020 09:20:01] "GET /api/order/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5070
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50152)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/CK/Git/QIF/inventory/proj/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/CK/Git/QIF/inventory/proj/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Users/CK/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Happening to me also, started after updating to Pycharm 2020.1.1

Comment: so how to fix it ?

Comment: @itjuba I couldn't fix, I turned to postman